# Rails rake task on Heroku: Disable displaying the SQL log on the screen

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, logging, heroku, rake-task

I am running a rails 3.2 app in Heroku Cedar stack.

When I  **locally** execute rake tasks that involve querying the database, the  screen log does not show the detail of the SQL queries.

On the other hand, when I run the same task **on the Heroku deployed app** (heroku run rake ...), there is a verbose output of every query executed by the rake task. I would like to **disable such detail** showing in the screen. Is it possible?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap your code in a `Rails.logger.silence` block:

```
task thing_doer: :environment do
  Rails.logger.silence { ThingDoer.call }
end
```

Comment: Can you share more about what you tried? Did you run it like `heroku run rake think_doer`? Are you sure you pushed your updated code to Heroku?

Comment: Yes. Using rails 3 and there are some bugs logged on github about `.silence` not working as expected, so perhaps it's because I'm working on such an old version of Rails.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest running these tasks in `detached` mode.  This will prevent output in your terminal, but still have output (anything written to `STDOUT` or `STDERR`) to the Heroku log files.

This would be run by:

`heroku run:detached rake ...`

There is [good documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/one-off-dynos#running-tasks-in-background) on this as well to help you out.  Hopefully this is what you're looking for.

Comment: thank you @CDub. The issue is that we need to have certain output on the screen. To be more precise, it is a script that we run before deploying, and we check if certain items of the database have certain state, and count how many. It is like we need to see this result: "XX (count) processes still open". But not all the query execution that becomes too verbose...

Comment: An alternative would be to tail the logs while you're running that rake task.  You could limit what you're looking for in the logs by filtering on the `run` task.  As long as you're writing those results you want to STDOUT, that should be all you'd see.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable logs if you put this code in your rake task:

```
dev_null = Logger.new("/dev/null")
Rails.logger = dev_null
ActiveRecord::Base.logger = dev_null
```